# Get mailchimp form (submit and email address ) on one line

Tags: css, wordpress, mailchimp

I new to get "email address and submit" in the same line. How can I get this?

Here is my css:

```
  .mc4wp-form-theme button, .mc4wp-form-theme input[type=submit], .mc4wp-form-theme input[type=button] {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        background: 0 0;
        text-shadow: none;
        filter: none;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Which form is this? Newletter form or custom post form? Send image

Comment: newsletter form (embebed from elementor)

Comment: Can you also add the HTML? elemntor is a little tricky

Comment: try adding this: `float: left;`